# [Vue warn]: Error in v-on handler: "SyntaxError: Unexpected token , in JSON at position 76"

Tags: javascript, json, vue.js, axios

While I am trying to add this JSON data into Database then it is giving me the above Error!

```
var tax_setting = '{ "total_tax_settings":  { "charge_tax": ' + this.taxInfoRadioButton + 
    ', "tax_settings" : [' +
    '{ "tax_name": ' + this.taxName + 
    ', "tax_rate": ' + this.taxRate +
    ', "tax_included_in_price": ' + this.taxIncludeInPrice + ' } ]}}';
```

Radio Button of this JSON:

```
<v-radio-group v-model="taxInfoRadioButton">
    <v-radio color="primary" label="Do not charge tax on purchases" value="1"></v-radio>
    <v-radio color="primary" label="Charge tax on purchase" value="2"></v-radio>
</v-radio-group>

data() {
  return {
     taxInfoRadioButton: '1'
  }
}
```

Text Field:

```
<v-text-field name="taxName" label="Tax Name" id="taxName" v-model="taxName"></v-text-field>
data() {
  return {
     taxName: ''
  }
}
```

Tax Rate is also same as above.

Select Option in JSON:

```
<v-select  hide-details v-bind:items="willTaxInclude"  v-model="taxIncludeInPrice"  label="Select"  single-line  menu-props="bottom" ></v-select>
data() {
  return {
     willTaxInclude: [
        { text: "Yes", value: 1 },
    { text: "No", value: 0 }
    ],
    taxIncludeInPrice: '0',
  }
}
```

Parse it in JSON format:

`var tax_setting = JSON.parse(tax_setting);`

I am passing this data to Database using `axios`

```
axios.post('/api/data/user/save-business-settings', {
    tax_setting: tax_setting,
}).then((res) => {
    console.log(res);
}).catch((err) => {
    console.log(err);
})
```

What is the problem I can't figure out Actually. Please help me.

Comment: why are you creating `tax_setting` as a string initially? why not just create the object right off?

Comment: String values in a JSON string must be wrapped in the double quotes. Ex. `'{ "tax_name": "' + this.taxName + '"' +`.

Comment: @depperm, I have to collect data and have to wrapped them into a `JSON` because I have to save them into Database.

Comment: @Teemu, Okay. But it is not creating problem!! I have stored others data like this. But I think what you mentioned it's the best approach. Thank you.

Comment: It was just a single example, there are more strings to be quoted in that JSON. As depperm said, you could have created an object directly, there's no need for a JSON here. If you need JSON, let JavaScript to [stringify](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/JSON/stringify) it to you from the live object.

Comment: But why it is giving `Syntax Error` here?

Comment: ```var payment_setting = '{ "payment_settings" : [' +
    '{ "cash": ' + this.cash + ', "online": ' + this.online +', "bank_transfer": ' + this.bankTransfer + ' } ]}';```  This is not giving me any Error!!

Comment: The error happens here: `var tax_setting = JSON.parse(tax_setting);`, because the JSON string you created is invalid, the string values must be wrapped in the double quotes. The original `tax_setting` is just a JS string.

Comment: You are right. :-) Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The number #1 rule to keep in mind when working with JSON is...

> NEVER ROLL YOUR OWN JSON

JSON is best created by first creating the object you want to serialise, then passing that to `JSON.stringify()`. Since you're using Axios, you don't even have to do that since Axios does it for you; you simply pass it the object you want POSTed.

```js
const tax_setting = {
  total_tax_settings: {
    charge_tax: this.taxInfoRadioButton,
    tax_settings: [{
      tax_name: this.taxName,
      tax_rate: this.taxRate,
      tax_included_in_price: this.taxIncludeInPrice
    }]
  }
}

axios.post('/api/data/user/save-business-settings', { tax_setting })
  .then(...)
```